# My Ether has been automatically sent to another address without knowing why

Tags: scam

I noticed that money i have withdrawn to my wallet:
0x0434ee9166a01adf4aab3e6693cc160b5152cb0c

instantly get sent to another wallet I dont own.

I check with: https://revoke.cash/ I have no contracts or other things signed that should allow this.

Is my wallet compromosised

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your wallet is compromised and a sweeper bot is active, sweeping your funds. Withdraw all of the funds, NFTs etc from it.